# Fancybox only works after second click

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

So I have a table where each cell is a name of a game and when you click it it needs to show in a fancybox the results of the user which clicked the cell (I use table Indexes to get the GameID and the Session variable to get userID) which will be used to load the results from a second PHP page.

If I click on a cell for the first time the fancybox will not display anything and after I close fancybox and click on any cell again it works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the whole javascript:

```
$(".jogos").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true,       
        'onComplete':function(element)
        {

            var gameIdx = $(element).index();
            var cateIdx  = $(element).parent().parent().index();
            var gameIdxPHP;
            var catIdxPHP;
            var gameID;
            var userId = '<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>'

            <?php 
                for ($i=1; $i<= count($categoryArray);$i++)
                {
                    for ($j=1; $j<=count($categoryArray[$i-1]->gamelist);$j++)
                    {
                        ?>
                        catIdxPHP = '<?php echo $i ?>' -1;
                        gameIdxPHP = '<?php echo $j ?>' -1;

                        if (catIdxPHP == cateIdx && gameIdxPHP == gameIdx)
                        {
                            gameID = '<?php echo $categoryArray[$i-1]->gamelist[$j-1]->GameID; ?>';
                            $("#graphic").load("backoffice/resUserNivel2short.php", {userId:userId,gameID:gameID}, function(){ });
                        }

                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>


        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="data">
        <div id="graphic">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample code of the link

```
<a href="#data" class="jogos" id="cat<?php echo $i; ?>jogo<?php echo $j; ?>" >
```

Comment: where is the click event for the cell? post the whole js. is the fancebox script inside the click handler?

Comment: there is no click event. Its an <a href="#data" >

Comment: oh right, post your html markup then

Comment: are u sure you got the .fancybox code in your document ready function?

Comment: it is inside document ready. I noticed that if I add: 'onCleanup':function(element)
  {
   $("#graphic").html("");
  } to my fancybox, it will never display the graphics, only a blank fancybox

Comment: I remember that I had the same problem. can you try adding a $('.jogos').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }) before your fancybox

Comment: Ive seen that solution already, the problem is that it now doesn't even open a fancybox instead of a blank fancybox. I think the problem is in the Load function which doesn't load the data quick enough to be displayed

Comment: but it opens the fancybox with the correct graphics on second click?

Comment: it doesn't open any graphic at all.

Comment: because the parent of your #data div has display none.. ill create an answer for you.

Comment: I know but thats not it, the fancybox automatically removes the display none. I tried with and without it, same thing happens. The problem is the load indeed, the first time it doesnt load fast enough, the second time I can see the first graphic appearing just before the second one is loaded on top of the first, then when I click the next one the third still shows the second for a moment. Highcharts take time to load, if I use only text, it shows it on first click!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have display:none on the parent of your fancybox therefor the grafic isnt displayed.

The Grafic element isn't inside the dom yet if you use display:none initially. Try to use clip: rect instead as a class and add/remove that class using the fancybox callbacks.

Try this code:

```
$('.jogos').fancybox({
        'onStart': function() {
            $("#data").removeClass('hidden');
        },
        'onClosed': function() {
            $("#data").addClass('hidden');
        }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { 
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  position: absolute;
)}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="data" class="hidden">
    <div id="graphic">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have just tried it. No changes, everything is the same. First time blank fancybox, second time works fine. Have you see my previous answer? If I load text instead of a highcharts graphic, it works on first try. Is there any way to reload/force update fancybox?

Comment: I kinda solved it, I added a fake graphic in the $('#graphic') div and now it displays on first try, despite not being positioned in the center of the screen, but I can solve that. Thanks for your help

Comment: using inline php is a very bad practice.. you should give each cell the data you need outside of the javascript. like if cell1 has game1 you can add a data-game-id="1" inside your html markup. and you can access that data attribute with $(this).data('game-id')

Comment: Users can't see the ID if use data variables?